# How to make advance search in Django?

Tags: python, django

Currently i am working in **Django** and more precisely in filter method.

According to my knowledge filter works like this. if i search "Apple iphone 7 plus" than it will find whole sentence in my records where it occurs but i want to modify this filter in following manner. i want to split the query in words and then find those words in document to search, like upper query should return those records which contains "apple" && "iphone" && "7" && "plus".

Can anybody tell me how can i improve my query. which builtin function in django can help me.

**My recent code looks like is following.**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def Filter_Mobiles(request,query):

   print(query)
   try:
      que = Q(SNR_Title__icontains=query )
   Mobile_all = Mobile_DB.objects.filter(que)

   except Mobile_DB.DoesNotExist:

       return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

please ignore syntax mistakes.

how can i modify this. is there any built in function to help me? please suggest me changes.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django text search with partial sentence match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594010/django-text-search-with-partial-sentence-match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution is:

```
que = Q()
for word in query.split():
    que &= Q(SNR_Title__icontains=word)
Mobile_all = Mobile_DB.objects.filter(que)
```

And you don't need the exception Mobile_DB.DoesNotExist, filter never raise it.

Comment: Wow! Never knew Boolean operators can be chained like that in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an OR query:

```
Mobile_DB.objects.filter(Q(SNR_Title__icontains='apple') | Q(SNR_Title__icontains='iphone'))
```

But it will still just create an SQL query witch will not be sufficient for complex searches.
I will advise you to check out http://haystacksearch.org/ witch is a module for Django that will allow you to easily connect complex search engines to your Django models.

Comment: How to automate your query for words picked out of your inputs?

Comment: OP is looking for an `AND` (`&`) query. He wants to fetch records that contain all the given words in the query. You have answered with an `OR` (`|`) query.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this solution works for you, Query each word and provide a union of all data. might be a bit slow for lot of records. I will suggest use stored procedure for more complex search.

```
queryset_final = None

for q in query.split(' '):
    que = Mobile_DB.objects.filter(Q(SNR_Title__icontains=q))
    if queryset_final:
        queryset_final = queryset_final | que
    else:
        queryset_final = que

Mobile_all = queryset_final.distinct()
```